# Decompose cell with multiple values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `pandas.DataFrame(...)` in the following format(working example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo1':[1,2,3], 'foo2': ["a:1, b:2", "d:4", "a:6, d:5"]})
df
   foo1      foo2
0     1  a:1, b:2
1     2       d:4
2     3  a:6, d:5
```

I would like to decompose the `foo2` cell values into columns(O/P df):

```
   foo1      foo2_a    foo2_b    foo2_d
0     1           1         2         0
1     2           0         0         4 
2     3           6         0         5
```

I could iterate all over the dataframe through index, store value for each row - BUT IT DOESN'T seem elegent.

Is there some `pandas` trick/ elegent/ pythonic solution to this problem ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
df.foo2.str.split(', ').apply(lambda l: pd.Series({e.split(':')[0]: int(e.split(':')[1]) for e in l})).fillna(0)
```

You get

```
     a    b    d
0  1.0  2.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  4.0
2  6.0  0.0  5.0
```

Note that once you get each row into a dictionary, you can transform it into a pandas `Series`, and this will be the result.

From this point, it is just a question of renaming the columns, and `concat`enating the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + `apply` with `list comprehension` for `dicts`. Then converting column to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) + [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html), [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) column `foo1`:

```
s = df['foo2'].str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: dict([y.split(':') for y in x]))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist()).fillna(0).add_prefix('foo2_').astype(int)
df = df[['foo1']].join(df1)
print (df)
   foo1  foo2_a  foo2_b  foo2_d
0     1       1       2       0
1     2       0       0       4
2     3       6       0       5
```

Comment: Some problem? If yes, can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

```
#find all the keys ('a','b','d',...)
d = {k:0 for k in df.foo2.str.extractall('([a-z]+)(?=:)').iloc[:,0].unique()}
#split foo2 and build a new DF then merge it into the existing DF.
pd.concat([df['foo1'].to_frame(), df.foo2.str.split(', ')\
   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(d,**dict([e.split(':') for e in x])))).add_prefix('foo2_')], axis=1)

Out[149]: 
   foo1 foo2_a foo2_b foo2_d
0     1      1      2      0
1     2      0      0      4
2     3      6      0      5
```